# Выделение запятыми междометия "Ну"

Tags: пунктуация, частица, междометие

Междометие "ну" ведь всегда должно выделяться запятыми, но почему не выделяется тут: "Ну что же ты студент". Бывают исключения?

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433953/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь "ну" частица.
Есть хороший прием для разграничения междометия и частицы, следовательно, для постановки запятой и ее отсутствия. Нужно произнести фрагмент предложения с "ну" или все предложение, если оно короткое. В случае если ударение во фразе падает на "ну", перед нами междометие, если нет, то частица.
Кстати, "студент" в вашем предложении — обращение, значит, надо выделить запятыми, здесь, понятно, одной )

Answer (score 2):

***Частицы о, ну, ах и др., употребляемые для выражения усилительного оттенка, в отличие от междометий запятыми не отделяются:***
а) частица о чаще всего употребляется при восклицательном обращении (см. § 101, п. 2) и перед словами да и нет (см. § 103, п. 1) например: Как хорошо ты, о море ночное! (Тютчев); О нет, мой младенец, ослышался ты (Жуковский);
б) частица ах обычно употребляется перед личными местоимениями ты и вы, за которыми следует обращение, например: Ах ты, обжора! (Крылов); Ах ты, мерзкое стекло! (Пушкин); Ах ты, степь моя, степь широкая! (Кольцов). Ср. также: Ах да, вспомнил наш вчерашний разговор;
в) **частица ну употребляется с усилительным значением, например:** ***Ну как не порадеть родному человечку! (Грибоедов); Ну что за шейка, что за глазки! (Крылов); Ну и жара выдалась! Ну нет, так не пойдет; Дайте ну хотя бы эту книгу.*** [См. здесь](http://lib.rus.ec/b/342635/read)

Answer (score 0):

***С** междометиями** (по форме) могут совпадать частицы. Имеющие усилительное значение частицы, в отличие от междометий, не отделяются знаками от слов, при которых они стоят:

- Например: - Ну пойди, пойди сюда; —
     Ну надо же! — Всё изумлялась Марья; —
     Ай не узнала?.***