# Запятая после "ну" в разговорных оборотах. Всегда ли нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, частица, междометие

Всегда ли ставиться запятая после "ну" в разговорных (речевых) оборотах. Я вот ее не очень часто хочу там ставить.
Ну, как поступать? Ну как правильно?

UP. Каждый вопрос уникален, ибо составляет уникальную комбинацию из букв.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11063/%D0%9

Comment: Пользуйтесь окном ИСКАТЬ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нет, не всегда.Нужно определиться, это междометие или усилительная частица.

1. Междометие. Выражает побуждение, удивление. Междометие «ну» интонационно отделяется от последующего слова и обособляется.

   *Ну, давай плясать! Становись!* А. Островский, За чем пойдешь, то и найдешь.

Если междометие «ну» выражает удивление, восхищение или недовольство, негодование, иронию, то оно не обособляется.

*Ну бал! Ну Фамусов! умел гостей назвать! Какие-то уроды с того света*. А. Грибоедов, Горе от ума.

Запятая также не ставится внутри неразложимых сочетаний со словами «ну тебя», «ну вас», «ну его», «ну их», а также сочетаний «ну и», «ну уж», «ну уж и». 
*«Да ну тебя к черту с твоими бумагами!» – дерзко хохоча, кричала Наташа.* М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита.

2. Частица. Служит для усиления последующего высказывания; то же, что «так, итак» (употребляется при подведении итогов); то же, что «допустим, положим». Интонационно не отделяется от последующих слов. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

   *Ну а если любит, то и сам приедет, и гостей привезет.* Ю. Домбровский, Факультет ненужных вещей. *Ведь видит же, какого я роста, и, значит, должен понять, что мне самое большее семь, ну восемь от силы, – зачем же тогда спрашивать?* В. Драгунский, Денискины рассказы.

Также не требует постановки знаков препинания сочетание ударной частицы «ну» с неопределенной формой глагола несовершенного вида (при обозначении неожиданного и резкого начала действия).

*А Игоша не дремлет: он ко мне – и ну зубами тянуть узлы; только батюшка отворотится, он петлю и вытянет; не прошло двух минут – и я снова очутился на ковре между игрушек, посредине комнаты.* В. Одоевский, Игоша.

Запятая также не ставится внутри сочетаний «ну да», «ну и что», «ну что», «ну что ж».

[НУ, междометие и частица | gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_501&layout=item)

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила. А я кстати помню Вас...
Кстати, а нужно ли в моем вышестоящем предложении слово "кстати" обособлять запятыми? :-)

Comment: Кстати - вводное, следовательно, обособляется.