# Стоит ли отделять запятой слово "ну"?

Tags: пунктуация

Ну, это не то чтобы врачеватель души - в самом деле это обычный, ничем не выделяющийся человек.

Стоит ли ставить запятую после "Ну"? Она ведь является в данном случае частицей и оказывает смысловое воздействие на последующую конструкцию, выражая дополнительно некоторое колебание, сомнение?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выделение запятыми междометия "Ну"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11063/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9d%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уверены, что частица, то не ставьте.
Я не вижу причин исключать вариант, что это междометие, которое требует после себя запятой. Решать автору.

Comment: А почему не стоит запятая перед "чтобы"?

Comment: @Владимир а это другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

После частиц запятая не ставится. Тогда "ну" произносится коротко и вообще без паузы.

Второй вариант - междометие, после которого должна стоять запятая. Тогда после "ну" явная пауза и слово (чуть) протягивается, выражая неудовлетворение (по отношению к предыдущим высказываниям).